# Can't figure out hover menu caret

Tags: css, menu, caret

Trying to set up a triangle caret on top of top-border.  It's a wordpress menu.
One of the problems is that it doesn't appear at all. And that's a major one :)
Another one, is i can't think of the way to attach it to top border.
live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr1-1/

```
<li>
<div class="care"></div>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu'  ) ); ?>

</li>
```

css

```
#menu li li:hover  {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #D62F2F;
border-top-width: 3px;
}

.care {
background-image: url(images/caret.png);
width: 16px;
height: 8px;
margin: 0 auto;
visibility: hidden;
}

#menu li li:hover > .care {
background-image: url(images/caret.png);
width: 16px;
height: 8px;
margin: 0 auto;
visibility: visible;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Can you tell me your requirement with sketch image please!

Comment: You aren't referencing the image file correctly?

Comment: i'm referencing it correctly for sure. My problems is in css  @Asraful soloveich.com/pr1-1/wp-content/themes/blankslate/images/mnud.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You never used the css rule .care for your entire html .so use it where you want to see.

```
.care {
    background-image: url("images/caret.png");
    height: 8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
```

Then you will able to see your caret.png image.
Hope the answer!
If you want to use it in li then add it like 
[image]

Comment: I added class "care" to li, and the whole menu disappeared.  And wouldn't it be easier to manipulate margins if it was in separate div?